while using amqp qpid proton a thread_local initialized when creating a stack object is crashing my thread when I start it a second time
I'm trying to understand the below crash and cannot get my head around why/if the thread_local has something to do with it.
Here is how the crash occurs, how I fixed it and my incomplete understanding asI do not expect it to crash initially (with a proton::container stack object)
I start a thread (let's call it ProtonThread, inheriting from thread and proton::messaging_handler) and in that thread main method I do proton::container::run(*this); in a scope.
This will trigger the https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton/blob/88850e2da63e37749536d64daf23c659c896fd2a/cpp/src/uuid.cpp#L47 for the generation of the id which means a thread_local is created in this thread.
Once the proton::container::run() will finish the scope will finish and the stack object is destroyed (at ; but I also tried with a variable).
The "engine" should not be impacted by this and get destroyed at thread exit. I do join the thread, see that I do a clean exit so it looks fine to me.
Then I start the thread again. Now I crash when I try to run the container.
One solution I found to this is to not use an stack object in the thread main function but a member in that class (ProtonThread). This way the proton::container member will be created from the thread constructing ProtonThread which makes the "engine" a thread_local on that thread.
This guaranteed that "engine" is alive as it's thread_local to another thread not ProtonThread.
Now, my expectation was that, even with ProtonThread the thread_local engine should work fine.
I would appreciate any hint on why this might not be the case
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f13ede8b94c in __pthread_kill_implementation () from /lib64/libc.so.6
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f13e6ffb640 (LWP 792836))]
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install cyrus-sasl-gssapi-2.1.27-21.el9.x86_64 cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.27-21.el9.x86_64 cyrus-sasl-plain-2.1.27-21.el9.x86_64 gdbm-libs-1.19-4.el9.x86_64 glibc-2.34-100.el9_4.4.x86_64 jsoncpp-1.9.5-1.el9.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.6.3-1.el9.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.21.1-2.el9_4.x86_64 libcom_err-1.46.5-5.el9.x86_64 libgcc-11.4.1-3.el9.x86_64 libnsl2-2.0.0-1.el9.x86_64 libselinux-3.6-1.el9.x86_64 libstdc++-11.4.1-3.el9.x86_64 libtirpc-1.3.3-8.el9_4.x86_64 libxcrypt-4.4.18-3.el9.x86_64 pcre2-10.40-5.el9.x86_64 qpid-proton-c-0.37.0-2.el9.x86_64 qpid-proton-cpp-0.37.0-2.el9.x86_64 zlib-1.2.11-40.el9.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007f13ede8b94c in __pthread_kill_implementation () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f13ede3e646 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f13ede287f3 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f13ede29130 in __libc_message.cold () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f13ede959f7 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007f13ede9671c in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007f13ede982f8 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#7  0x00007f13ede99809 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#8  0x00007f13ee73a75e in malloc (size=<optimized out>) at ../include/rtld-malloc.h:56
#9  allocate_dtv_entry (size=<optimized out>, alignment=8) at ../elf/dl-tls.c:730
#10 allocate_and_init (map=0x1f575e0) at ../elf/dl-tls.c:759
#11 tls_get_addr_tail (ti=0x7f13ed3fde58, dtv=0x7f13e00018f0, the_map=0x1f575e0) at ../elf/dl-tls.c:970
#12 0x00007f13ee73e76c in __tls_get_addr () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/tls_get_addr.S:55
#13 0x00007f13ed3dd187 in proton::uuid::random() () from /lib64/libqpid-proton-cpp.so.12
#14 0x00007f13ed3c6bfe in proton::container::container(proton::messaging_handler&) () from /lib64/libqpid-proton-cpp.so.12


Without knowing details about the library you are using, your stack trace suggests that your actual problem is that malloc() wants to kill your program via abort(). It typically only does that when glibc's malloc() detects that you have a memory error, i.e. that something in your code overwrote parts of the book-keeping information relied upon by the memory allocator. You could try to compile your program with -fsanitize=address to find the actual culprit, because you are likely just seeing a symptom in your stack trace, not the root cause.

The issue was the work_queue that was backed by the container (https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.36.0/proton/cpp/api/classproton_1_1work__queue.html) was accessed after the container was destroyed. This is obviously wrong and created the issue in my program.
